# Image does not get rendered in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

I fiddled around with the django `ImageField`,

and I got following models for example

```
class Card(models.Model):
    name        =   models.TextField()
    mana        =   models.IntegerField()
    rarity      =   models.IntegerField(choices=RARITY_CHOICES)
    card_class  =   models.IntegerField(choices=CLASS_CHOICES)
    card_set    =   models.IntegerField(choices=SET_CHOICES)
    card_type   =   models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Weapon(Card):
    damage      =   models.already created a deck with some cards in the django admin interface. Now finally I wanted to render it with a custom view in my template with this viewIntegerField()
    durability  =   models.IntegerField()
    image       =   models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/ubuntu/illuminated/media/images/weapons/')

class Deck(models.Model):
    name            =   models.CharField(max_length=20)
    spell_cards     =   models.ManyToManyField(Spell, blank=True)
    weapon_cards    =   models.ManyToManyField(Weapon, blank=True)
    minion_cards    =   models.ManyToManyField(Minion, blank=True)
```

I already created a deck with some cards in the django admin interface. Now finally I wanted to render it with a custom view in my template with this view

```
class ShowDeck(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'hsguides/deck.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowDeck, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['deck'] = Deck.objects.all()
        return context
```

And this simple template
already created a deck with some cards in the django admin interface. Now finally I wanted to render it with a custom view in my template with this view

```
{% for foo in deck.all %}
  {{ foo.name }}
  <br>
  {% for weapon in foo.weapon_cards.all %}
    {{ weapon.name }}
    <img src="{{ weapon.image }}" height="{{ weapon.image.height }}" width="{{ weapon.image.width }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The names are getting rendered, and when I have a look at the page source the image url, width and height as well but the image simply does not show up.

When I click on *View Image* in my browser I see the following error

> Using the URLconf defined in illuminated.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> ^admin/
> ^account/
> ^guides/
> ```
>
> The current URL,
>   home/ubuntu/illuminated/media/images/weapons/Truesilver_Champion_Gold_ktmWGK8.png,
>   didn't match any of these

It currently looks like this

[image]

The page source looks like this

```
  Basic Paladin
  <br>

    Truesilver Champion
    <img src="/home/ubuntu/illuminated/media/images/weapons/Truesilver_Champion_Gold_ktmWGK8.png" height="396" width="289">
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short:**

---

Set the upload_to attribute to `images/weapons/` and add

```
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

to your root urls.py.

Also make sure in your settings you define `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**Explanation:**

---

In your `models.py` you are setting the upload_to attribute of the `ImageField` in `class Weapon` to an absolute path  on your local filesystem : `/home/ubuntu/illuminated/media/images/weapons`.

In the context of your browser however any path starting with `/` is interpreted as absolute with regards to the host. In case your hostname is localhost and your server is running on port 8000 it will look for the file
`http://localhost:8000/home/ubuntu/......./weapons/file.jpg`.

When django processes the request it tries to match the requested path which starts with `home`, but as you have no route configured to resolve `home` you get this error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer "In the context of your browser however any path starting with / is interpreted as absolute with regards to the host". That made sense! :D